# Best way to have collections of items from a table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a list of items in a table and I'd like to create collections of those items in a new table. I've looked at has_many and has_many :through but I'm not sure those are the right choice and I'm not entirely sure how they'd work in my situation.

One special circumstance is that I want the items from the table to be identified by a unique field called typeID instead of the normal ID.

More information:

My model:

```
  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "typeID"
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "basePrice",   :precision => 17, :scale => 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 :null => false
  end
```

I have a bunch of products and I need to have some of them bundled into packages (to sell as a bundle) that I can work with. The products will need to be able to be included in multiple different bundles.

Comment: What do you mean you want to create collections *in* a new table? Maybe tell how you plan to use these relations to give us a better idea of what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've been banging on this for the last 3 hours and I'm really tired. I have a bunch of products I sell, I'd like to create packages of those products and I need some way to bundle them into packages or collections. I assume I'd be using a table to keep track of the package names and what items are in the package.

Comment: Hah yeah I know what that's like. Give some code examples though (like what your models look like), will make it easier to give you an answer.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I'll edit my original post.

Comment: So that's your migration for the products table. What other tables are you planning to have? I'm trying to understand how these *collections* of yours come into play.

Comment: Ah. I just need to be able to display the packages (as a list of products) on a page. I don't really care how that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a similar approach to Samiron's if each product only belongs to a single package.

However, if that's not the case, I'd recommend has_many :through instead. Here's an example of that:

```
class Package
  has_many :product_listings
  has_many :products, :through => :product_listings

  # allows you to make convenient create/build calls like i do below
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_listings
end

class Product
  # defining these relations are only necessary if you want to be able to get all
  # packages a product exists in
  has_many :product_listings
  has_many :packages, :through => :product_listings
end

class ProductListing
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :product

  attr_accessible :package_id, :product_id
end
```

Then, in some view, you could do something like this:

```
Package.all.each do |package|
  <%= package.name %>  # or whatever attribute the package has
  package.products.each do |product|
    <%= product.name %>  # or whatever attribute the product has
  end
end
```

**Edit**

See the addition to the Package model.

Here's how you'd add products to a package:

```
package = Package.create(:name => 'some package')

# Rails naming convention for attributes is snake_case, not camelCase (if you care) 
product = Product.create(:name => 'mouse', :base_price => 20.00)

package.product_listings.create(:product_id => product.id)
```

Comment: This is probably exactly what I need. However I'm a little hazy as to how the interaction actually happens. Will I need to manually make the ProductListing entries to create the packages?

Comment: My understanding is that you will be creating a package, and adding products to that package right?

Comment: Ya this is exactly what you need... i missed the relation part :P

Comment: Static packages I'll create and list. For example: A motherboard, CPU and ram, as a package deal that I also sell separately.

Comment: In that case, check out this gem - http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin. After setting up the relations/schema I described, ActiveAdmin could save you some time in creating an easy interface for you to manage the creation of packages/products.

Answer (score 3):

In the very simplest case you just need a `one to many` or `many to many` relationships

**One To Many:** Assuming that a package can contain multiple items

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belogs_to :package
end
```

In this way you can bundle your `products` in a package.

**many To Many *(Probably you need this)* :** Based on the last update of your question.

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :packages
end
```

Now, your package should also have a price column that includes the price of the belonging products ( may be with some amount of discount :). Is that helped?

---

You may not need this: 
*However, if your products are divided into several types (food, electronics, apparel etc) and you want to have separate model for each of them inheriting `Product` then you just need to have a `Single Table Inheritance`.*

---